# Datatype not understood error when appending dataframes in Azure ML Studio

Tags: python, pandas, azure, dataframe, append

I am trying to append one dataframe to another with the same data format in Azure ML Studio.
The script is very simple, but outputs a "Data type not understood" error and I cannot figure out why.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def azureml_main(dataframe1, dataframe2):

    print('Input pandas.DataFrame #1:\r\n\r\n{0}'.format(dataframe1))

    new_dataframe1 = dataframe1.append(dataframe2)

    return new_dataframe1,
```

This is how the input data format is like:

```
Input example:
2017-10-24T08:59:59.3+00:00     abcde   auto    41  0917D884    F48  36
2017-10-24T09:00:10.57+00:00    abcde   auto    52  0917H349    F20  65
2017-10-24T09:00:15.49+00:00    abcde   auto    7   0917D833    F48x 30
2017-10-24T09:00:15.91+00:00    abcde   auto    55  0917H366    F20  34
2017-10-24T09:00:16.49+00:00    abcde   auto    60  0917D954    F48  1
```

Error message:

```
Error 0085: The following error occurred during script evaluation, please view the output log for more information:
---------- Start of error message from Python interpreter ----------
Caught exception while executing function: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\server\invokepy.py", line 199, in batch
    odfs = mod.azureml_main(*idfs)
  File "C:\temp\ab81dec1cf8542af837324f3421cb72d.py", line 31, in azureml_main
    new_dataframe1 = dataframe1.append(dataframe2)
  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4322, in append
    verify_integrity=verify_integrity)
  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 835, in concat
    return op.get_result()
  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 1025, in get_result
    concat_axis=self.axis, copy=self.copy)
  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4474, in concatenate_block_managers
    for placement, join_units in concat_plan]
  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4474, in <listcomp>
    for placement, join_units in concat_plan]
  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4571, in concatenate_join_units
    for ju in join_units]
  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4571, in <listcomp>
    for ju in join_units]
  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4825, in get_reindexed_values
    missing_arr = np.empty(self.shape, dtype=empty_dtype)
TypeError: data type not understood
Process returned with non-zero exit code 1

---------- End of error message from Python  interpreter  ----------
Start time: UTC 10/26/2017 07:22:43
End time: UTC 10/26/2017 07:23:05
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are there same dtypes of columns? `print (dataframe1.dtypes)` and `print  (dataframe2.dtypes)`

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked and somehow the header columns were mixed up.
Correcting that fixed the issue!

Thanks!

Comment: How did you fix the mix-up?